# $check value is whole model object in CakePHP validation behavior

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, validation, behavior

I'm trying to implement a custom validation behavior across several models in Cake.  I'm new to the framework and to php in general, and may be prone to silly errors.

The problem I'm running into is that the first parameter to my custom validation function is being filled with the model that is being validated instead of array('fieldname'=>'input') which the documentation seems to say should be there.  What I've got is:

```
class Policy extends AppModel {
  var $actsAs = array('JsonValidation');
  var $validate = array(
    'field1' => array(
      'rule' => 'myValidationRule',
      'message' => 'Please enter valid stuff.'
    ),
    'field2' => array(
      'rule' => myValidationRule',
      'message' => 'Please enter valid my.'
    ));
    ....

class MyValidationBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

  function myValidationRule($check, $allowEmpty = false){

    debug($check);  //prints out the Policy model

    $input = array_shift($check);  //errors since $check isn't an array
    debug($input);
    if($allowEmpty && trim($input) == "") return true;
    if(isValid($input)) return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how I can get the user's input in this context?

Thanks,
Loren

Working solution:

```
  var $validate = array(
      'rules' => array(
        'rule' => array('myValidationRule', true),
        'message' => 'Please enter something valid.'
      ),
      'rule_parms' => array(
        'rule' => array('myValidationRule', true),
        'message' => 'Please enter something valid.'
      ));
```

```
  function myValidationRule($Model, $check, $allowEmpty){
    $input = array_shift($check);
    if($allowEmpty && trim($input) == "") return true;
    if(valid($input) == null) return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the [book here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1074/Creating-behavior-methods), the first parameter of a behavior method is always a reference to the calling model.

Comment: Ahah!  I come from a java-land and am not used to the idea of my functions parameters changing, but yes, I just needed one more argument.  Thanks!